# Finding parent of a component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, graphics

In my application, I took a panel and to that I added an image by giving some image path. To that image I added DrawingArea(custom) object and started drawing. After free hand drawing I'm adding that to its parent(by giving `this.addChild(graph);`). Here this indicates what? What can I give instead of `this`(especially in case of removing a particular child)? Pardon me, if its not clear.

```
    private function StartMarking(eve:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!eve.buttonDown)
        {
            isDrawing = false;
        }

        x2 = mouseX;
        y2 = mouseY;
        if (isDrawing)
        {
            drawColor = 0x000000;
            markUp.graphics.lineStyle(2, drawColor);
            markUp.graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
            markUp.graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);

            drawingStr += x1 + "_"+ y1 +"_";
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;

            this.addChild(markUp);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear enough. Provide us some code, please.

Comment: Here this refers to the object of the class in which the handler StartMarking is present.

Comment: this always refer's to current class's object. If you are in <s:Panel>..</Panel> then this refer's to Panel class instance object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove a component from its parent:

```
if (parent) parent.removeChild(this);
```

Add the direct child ("child") to the parent:

```
if (parent) parent.addChild(child);
```

The latter will remove the child from the current compenent and adds it instead to the parent of the current component so that both (current and child) are now children of the parent of the current component. Alright?